# How to detect when Modernizr has finished all tests, including asyncronous

Tags: modernizr

So as i learned Modernizr also ships with asynchronous tests, e.g. videoautoplay, the question arose how i know it is finished. I know that you can use Modernizr.on(feature,cb) but there's gotta be a more general approach, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist, but there is an [open issue for it](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1039).

For the time being, you would basically just want to keep track of your async detects, and use `Modernizr.on` to decrement a counter until all have run